# Formula to Search for Data in One Column, then Apply Formula

Tags: excel

I am working on a personal budget sheet in excel, and it's formatted based on my pay dates, to provide more drilled-down information. I have attached an example of it below for reference.

I would like to put a formula into `J2`, `J3`, and `J4` which will take the data in cells `C9:C26` and `H9:H16`, match it to the date in cells `D2:D4`, then subtract the expenses in `D9:D26` and `I9:I16` from `E2`, `E3`, and `E4`.

As you can see, I have just individually summed the cells; however, I would like a formula to be able to adjust as I change the value in cells `C9:C26` and `H9:H16`.

I have found that I can do it with ONE cell, but not multiple or a range. This is the formula I used, and I cannot find a way to make it apply to the entire range of cells: `=IF(C14=D3,E3-D14)`

I've also tried: `=IF(C9:C25=D3,E3-D9:D25)` -- I know this formula doesn't work and why. I cannot figure out how to get column C to correspond with column D.

[The Budget Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ3NP.png)
[image: The Budget Sheet]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I moved the Income / Expenses / Difference cells next to each other to remove some of the clutter. I like to see everything horizontally and at once, without having to scroll down, which is  why I had two sets of data. Though, with December having three pay periods, there is much more data than there normally would be. I am definitely still trying to figure out the best and most efficient layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `SumIf()`.

In cell J2, put this formula: `=SumIf($C$9:$C$25,$I2,$D$9:$D$25)+SumIf($H$9:$H$25,$I2,$I$9:$I$25)` and drag down the three cells.

With that, you can add `E2-[formula]` to subtract all that from `E2`. Or of course, just do `e2-J2` instead.  I think that should do what you're looking for.  If it's not quite it, let me know and I can tweak.

Comment: Thanks so much! The formula above was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @lammie - if this works, would you mind marking as the answer (click the check mark left of the post)?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have more than 1 criteria go with SUMIFS
Yes, with S

[image]